# Неизвестный скрытый div с непонятными атрибутами в футере

Tags: html

При верстке сайта решил,как обычно в firefox просмотреть разметку, заметил непонятный div с несуществующими атрибутами и какими то данными. В других браузерах этого нет. Причем на некоторых сайтах проверяю - он есть,на других -нет. Попробовал все дополнения браузера отключить - блок не исчезает. Конечно, можно переустановить Firefox, но хотелось бы узнать на будущее, что это[image: скрин этого дива] за див, откуда он генерится? В веб-разработке недавно, но раньше такого ни разу не замечал. Что только не передумал: и скрытый майнер, и код-шпион. Антивирус стоит и не ругается.
Вот код:

```
<code>
    <div id="extwaiimpotscp" style="display:none" v="{8cda" f="ZXpoalpHRTVZMlUyTFRjNE9UTXROR1kwTnkxaFl6Y3dMV0UyTlRJeE5XTmxZekk0T0gwPQ==" q="4d3a5c00" c="63.22" i="67.51" u="20.96" s="8d4e4c40" w="false" vn="0tren"></div>
</code>
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент нет API позволяющего отслеживать источник изменения DOM, насколько мне известно. Так же из вопроса совершенно не ясно, в чём может быть причина появления скрипта.
Поэтому предлагаю применить небольшой хак, может быть, он позволит отследить источник изменений:

```html
<script>
  function traceCall(old){ var _old = old; return function(){ console.log('[CALL] ', old, ' at ', new Error().stack); return old.call(this, arguments); }}
  document.body.append = traceCall(document.body.append)
  document.body.appendChild = traceCall(document.body.appendChild)
</script>
```

Добавить этот код, можно после тэга body. Он отследит вызовы основных методов модификации DOM.

Comment: ,я вставил данный скрипт в разметку, обновлял страницу, смотрел в консоль - никакой информации, только стандартное сообщение "Перешел на страницу" и т. д.

Comment: попробуйте у дива почстить стиль, так чтобы он отображался: display:block

Comment: я уже до этого так пробовал, и высоту задавал - он показывался пустым местом. https://monosnap.com/file/5kzWkWtDhp5j1fm4h3RpgJiF8M76dg

Comment: Если в самом начале body мой скрипт добавите и не поможет, тогда, уж без полного перебора всей страницы не обойтись

Comment: я данный скрипт не убирал из кода, когда к диву применял display:block. Причем он (неизвестный div) добавляется и на некоторых сайтах, на которые я заходил и специально проверял, открывая инспектор в Firefox.

Comment: Вот, например на сайте htmlbook.ru https://monosnap.com/file/1QLvfWQvL6HfR29NMRJ0NIYIsnnRX5

Answer (score 1):

После двух дней поисков нашел причину. Оказывается, я не все дополнения в FireFox отключил. После отключения "Гугл переводчик" div перестал появляться. Соответственно, после включения опять на тех же сайтах появлялся неизвестный div в футере. Но теперь, хотя бы, понятно, что это не что-то вредоносное. Все равно, спасибо за участие в проблеме.

Comment:  Ох уж эти дополнения. Имеется в виду https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/google-translator-for-firefox/ ?

Comment: FLCL нет, вот этот https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/inline-google-translate/?src=search